# Why $\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid N=0\right]=\mathbb{E}X+1$?

Tags: probability

First step in a game one throws three fair dice. Each step, if 6 is shown on
one or more of them, those dice are removed and the game continues
with the dice that are left. The game ends when there are no more
dice.

Let $N$ be the number of dice showing $6$ after the first throw,
and let $X$ be the total numbers of steps in the game.

Im trying to understand why $\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid N=0\right]=\mathbb{E}X+1$
?

I understand why $\left[X\mid N=0\right]\geq1$, so I guess we can say that
$\left[X\mid N=0\right]=1+Y$ where $Y$ is the total number of steps
minus one in a game which we know didn't end in the first step. Does
it follow from this that $\left[X\mid N=0\right]=1+X$ ? If so, why?

Comment: If you get no $6$s in the first throw, then in effect you start again at the beginning, having thrown once

Comment: @Henry I see that, but i'm struggling to see how $\left[X\mid N=0\right]$ can be expressed with $X$. I mean, how does the total number of steps in a specific game which didn't end after the first step can be equal to the total number of steps in that game plus one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have $[X|N=0] = 1+Y$, where $Y$ is the total number of steps minus one in a game where *no sixes were rolled on the first step* (not a game which *didn't end* on the first step as you stated; that would include $N=1$ and $N=2$ cases). We can consider $Y$ to be counting the number of steps from the second step onward. Then the important point here is that $Y$ and $X$ are **identically distributed**: if we've already rolled the dice once, got no sixes, and are not counting that step, we're in the exact same position as we would be if we were starting the game.

Since $Y$ and $X$ are identically distributed, $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[X]$. Thus $$\mathbb{E}[X|N=0] = \mathbb{E}[1+Y] = 1 + \mathbb{E}[Y] = 1 + \mathbb{E}[X]$$

Comment: 1. Cant $N$ be also $0$ there?
2. So we cant actually say that $\left[X\mid N=0\right]=1+X$, but only that their expected values are equal right?

Comment: @Jon 1. Where do you mean by "there"? 2. Absolutely correct.

Comment: There where you wrote "that would include... cases"

Comment: @Jon Yes, it would also include $N=0$ cases. But my point was that "a game which didn't end on the first step" would be two _broad_ a criterion. We know more information than that: we know the game didn't end on the first step, and we threw no sixes. If all we knew were that the game didn't end on the first step, we couldn't say $Y$ and $X$ were identically distributed, because we don't know whether we're throwing $3$ dice, $2$, or $1$ now

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if you start with $k$ dice, and define $N_k$ and $X_k$ similarly, then:

$$E(X_k\mid N_k=i)=1+E(X_{k-i})$$

This is because if your first step gets $i$ sixes, then the expected number of steps total is $1$ for this step and the expected number of step for the game starting with $k-i$ dice. (Where $X_0$ is identically $0.$)

---

So when $k>0$ you get: $$E(X_k)=\sum_{i=0}^kP(N_k=i)E(X_k\mid N_k=i)=1+\frac{1}{6^k}\sum_{i=0}^{k}5^{k-i}\binom{k}{i}E(X_{k-i})$$

Re-arranging, you get a recursion:

$$E(X_k)=\frac{6^k+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\binom{k}{j}5^kE(X_j)}{6^k-5^k}$$